# Correlation when one of the variables has different measures and scales

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, correlation, pearson-correlation

I am investigating how human performance on machine learning tasks is affected by the data size. Basically, I have to lists, each of size 30: the first list contains the data size (the number of evaluation samples) for each task, and the second list contains the corresponding human performance on each task. I was wondering what is the best to compute the correlation between the two lists if each task has a different evaluation measure, i.e., the values in the second list are from different evaluation measures, and thus have different scales and are computed differently. Are Pearson's and Spearman's correlation valid to be used in my case?

Thank in advance!

Comment: What do you have different metrics in list B, if you really wanna check on the size effect only?

Comment: Hi @GadaaDhaariGeek! For example, I have k-way classification tasks and k varies across tasks, some tasks might use Accuracy as the evaluation metric, some use F1, some use an uncommon metric.

Comment: Can you post how your data look like? and what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I wouls also suggest that you go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand a better way of asking questions so that you be detailed about it.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but suitable for stats.stackexchange.com rather than SO since it is not about programming.